# Add Max(Count(column)) in SQL MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2016

I have the following example dataset and as you can see the column X is the class ID, column Y is each class name, and finally column Z is the other universities class ID used for each subject. The goal is to get X, and Z with a grouping by X and get the most common ID used by Z (Other universities).

Sheet 1:

| X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 22 | 122 |
| 123 | 22 | 123 |
| 123 | 22 | 122 |
| 256 | 21 | 256 |
| 256 | 21 | 255 |
| 341 | 33 | 400 |
| 341 | 33 | 400 |

The outcome should be:

| X | Z |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 122 |
| 256 | 255 |
| 341 | 400 |

I tried by adding the following query, but it is only returning the maximum from all the the table but not only for each value in column Z.

```html
SELECT Sheet1.X, Sheet1.Z
  FROM Sheet1
  GROUP BY Sheet1.X, Sheet1.Z
  HAVING COUNT(Sheet1.Z) =
    (SELECT MAX(sheet2.count) FROM
        (SELECT Sheet1.X, Sheet1.Z, COUNT(Sheet1.Z) AS count
        FROM Sheet1
        GROUP BY Sheet1.X, Sheet1.Z) as sheet2);
```

Any suggestion of what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a real pain in MS Access.  But if you want *one* row per `X`, then you can do:

```
SELECT s1.X, s1.Z
FROM Sheet1 as s1
GROUP BY s1.X, s1.Z
HAVING s1.Z = (SELECT TOP (1) s2.Z
               FROM Sheet1 as s2
               WHERE s2.X = s1.X
               GROUP BY s2.Z
               ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, s2.Z
              );
```

If you want multiple rows in the event of ties, then use:

```
SELECT s1.X, s1.Z
FROM Sheet1 as s1
GROUP BY s1.X, s1.Z
HAVING COUNT(*) IN (SELECT TOP (1) COUNT(*)
                    FROM Sheet1 as s2
                    WHERE s2.X = s1.X
                    GROUP BY s2.Z
                   );
```

I should note that this would be simpler in just about any other database.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply Gordon, but actually none of those examples are working. I am wondering if it is because of sheet2 stated in your examples it is just a duplication of the current table Sheet1 or are you considering other option to get that table? I appreciate your help.

Comment: @JuanEspinosa . . . That was a typo.  Your question only mentions one table so this should only refer to one table.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! this clearly solves my issue. I have to learn to think in that way.